# append() doesn't append in last selected element

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with jQuery's append.

When I try to append a cached item, append() doesn't append the item in the last selected element when the "Cache" button is pressed twice or more.

append() works without any problems if the item I want to append is selected everytime before the call to append.

```
var origin = $('#origin').children().clone();
var destiny = $('.destiny');

//Doesn't work well :/
$('#cache').click(function(event) {
  destiny.append(origin);
});

//Works fine
$('#no-cache').click(function(event) {
  var origin = $('#origin').children().clone();
  destiny.append(origin);
});
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```js
(function() {

  var origin = $('#origin').children().clone();
  var destiny = $('.destiny');

  $('#cache').click(function(event) {
    destiny.append(origin);
  });

  $('#no-cache').click(function(event) {
    var origin = $('#origin').children().clone();
    destiny.append(origin);
  });

  $('#reset').click(function(event) {
    destiny.empty();
  });

})();
```

```css
#d1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#d2 {
  background-color: green;
}

#d3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="origin">
  <p>
    Hi, I'm a paragraph
  </p>
</div>
<button id="cache">With Cache</button>
<button id="no-cache">Without Cache</button>
<button id="reset">Reset!</button>

<div id="d1" class="destiny">
  <p>Destiny 1</p>
</div>

<div id="d2" class="destiny">
  <p>Destiny 2</p>
</div>

<div id="d3" class="destiny">
  <p>Destiny 3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You have one child p element that your cloning and trying to append it to three different destiny divs.  What is your desired result?

Comment: That the "origin" gets copied to all "destinies". (Sorry if I can't wright well, English is not my main language).

Comment: I think in cache code, you are at first appending `origin` to `destiny`, its fine. But when you click the same button of cache, `destiny` will contain previous `origin`s and will append more `origin` to new data.

Comment: Mmm, so why is appending the origin's content in the first 2 destinies and not in the last?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one 'p' element and there are three 'destiny' elements.  A dom node can only have one parent.  If you want to copy it to all the destiny elements you will have to clone multiple times.

Updated it to not clone.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var origin = $('#origin');
  var destiny = $('.destiny');
  
  $('#cache').click(function() {
    destiny.append(origin.html());
  });
  
  $('#reset').click(function() {
    destiny.empty();
  });
});
```

```css
    #d1 {
      background-color: red;
    }

    #d2 {
      background-color: green;
    }

    #d3 {
      background-color: blue;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="origin">
      <p>
        Hi, I'm a paragraph
      </p>
    </div>
    <button id="cache">With Cache</button>
    <button id="reset">Reset!</button>

    <div id="d1" class="destiny">
      <p>Destiny 1</p>
    </div>

    <div id="d2" class="destiny">
      <p>Destiny 2</p>
    </div>

    <div id="d3" class="destiny">
      <p>Destiny 3</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Or append the html() as the other solution suggested.

Comment: That means I can't cache the p element?

Comment: You could cache it, but you will need to clone for each place you want to append it to.

Comment: I didn't want to clone it every time. But it seems is the only way. I will wait for other answers to see if there is another way. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You may find this useful

**[WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hemal_301080/kkswrraj/4/)**

```
(function() {

  var origin = $('#origin').html();
  var destiny = $('.destiny');

  $('#cache').click(function(event) {
    destiny.append(origin);
  });

  $('#no-cache').click(function(event) {
    var origin = $('#origin').children().clone();
    destiny.append(origin);
  });

  $('#reset').click(function(event) {
    destiny.empty();
  });

})();
```

Comment: This works well. And there is one call to html(). I like it.